# $\overline{L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^p(\mathbb{R})} = L^p$ for $1 < p < 2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Is $\displaystyle \overline{L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^p(\mathbb{R})} = L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $1 < p < 2$ ? I know this holds for $p = 2$. But, I am not able to find any source about the case when $1 < p < 2$.

Comment: On which measured space are defined your $L^p$'s ?

Comment: @OliverDiaz How is $f_n\in L_1$ ?

Comment: @cabmetric: because $f_n$  is a simple function!  Any simple function $\phi$ that is in $L_p$ for some $1\leq p<\infty$ is also in  $L_r$ for any $1\leq r<\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple functions in $L_1$ are dense in any $L_p$ ($1\leq p<\infty$). For any function $f\in L_p$ there is a sequence of simple functions $f_n$ such the $|f_n|\nearrow|f|$. Then $|f_n-f|^p\leq 2^p|f|$ and by monotone convergence $\|f_n-f\|_p\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. Notice that  $f_n\in L_1\cap L_p$, for $f_n$ is simple and $|f_n|\leq |f|$.

Comment: Are all simple functions in $L_1$ ?

Comment: No, they aren't. Remember that integrability of simple functions depends on the sets where they are not $0$.

Comment: How did you get a sequence $(f_n)$ such that $(f_n)$ goes to $f$ pointwisely and $|f_n|$ goes increasingly to $|f|$ ?

Comment: @blamethelag: that is a standard thing to do. For $f\geq0$ you can consider $\phi_n=\sum^{n2^n-1}_{j=0}2^{-n}j\mathbb{1}(2^{-n}j<|f|\leq 2^{-n}(j+1)) + n\mathbb{1}(|f|>n)$. for a general function consider $f=f_+-f_-$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I am struggling with this line: For any function $f \in L_p$ there is a simple function $f_n$ such that $|f_n|\nearrow|f|$.  How can we say this ?

Comment: @OliverDiaz: I am not able to understand how you arrived at that particular example. Would you kindly explain.

Comment: To simplify things, suppose $f\geq0$. For any $x$ in the domain of $f$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, if $f(x)<n$, there is $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $$k2^{-n}\leq f(x)<2^{-n}(k+1)$$ Take $k=[2^nf(x)]$.The sets $\{x:k2^{-n}\leq f(x)<2^{-n}(k+1)\}$, $k=0,\ldots, n2^n-1$, and $\{x:f(x)>n\}$ are measureble (for $f$ is measurable); hence, the simple function $f_n=\sum^{2^n-1}_{k=1}k2^{-n}\mathbb{1}_{\{x:k2^{-n}\leq f(x)<2^{-n}(k+1)\}} + n\mathbb{1}_{\{x:f(x)>n\}}$ is measurable and $0\leq f_n\leq f$ (notice how the values of $f_n$ are chosen. For more general $f$, apply the argument to $f_+$ and $f_-$.

Comment: @cabmetric: Again, for $f\geq0$, notice that $|f(x)-f_n(x)|\leq 2^{-n}$ for whenever $f(x)<n$. Since $f$ is in $L_p$, $f(x)$ is finite almost surely. So, if $f(x)<\infty$, then t is clear that $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$. Similar argument works for general function $f=f_+-f_-$.

Answer (score 1):

For $f \in L^p$ we can define
$$ f_n = f1_{B(0,n)}1_{|f| < n} \in L¹ \cap L^p.$$
Then $(f_n)$ converges pointwisely to $f$ with domination $f$ in $L^p$. Thus by the dominated convergence theorem the convergence is in $L^p$.

Comment: What does $f1_{B(0,n)}1_{|f| < n}$ mean ?

Comment: I denote $1_E$ for the indicator function of $E$ : $1_E(x) = 1$ if $x \in E$ and $1_E(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you admit the fact that the space $C_{0}$ of continuous functions with compact support is dense in $L^{p}$, then the statement goes through immediately:

$C_{0}\subseteq L^{1}\cap L^{p}\subseteq L^{p}$, then $L^{p}=\overline{C_{0}}\subseteq\overline{L^{1}\cap L^{p}}\subseteq\overline{L^{p}}$.